# How to designate specified records based on the date in huge Oracle table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, plsql

I have a huge table, 500 million records. I've got to divide this table into groups (partitions) on the base of 4 attributes.

Within each group I have to pick (set a flag) newest record and subsequent records if the difference in date is greater than or equal to 7 days (choose the latest entry from 7-days period).

I think the table is too big to make calculations on it. Should I split it into several smaller ones? But all records of one group have to be in the same table.

Is there any way to designate appropriate records using only SQL (without fetching it to PL/SQL arrays)? This is a one-off operation.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Example (one group - attributes and date dd-mm-yyyy format):

1. [A1 A2 A3 A4] 08-05-2018 (flag 1 - newest one)
2. [A1 A2 A3 A4] 06-05-2018 (flag 0 - difference less than 7 days)
3. [A1 A2 A3 A4] 01-05-2018 (flag 1 - difference greater/equal 7 days)
4. [A1 A2 A3 A4] 30-04-2018 (flag 0 - difference less than 7 days - relative to record 3)
5. [A1 A2 A3 A4] 10-04-2018 (flag 1 - difference greater/equal 7 days - relative to record 3)

Comment: So for each key I look at the newest record and flag it 1. Then I look for the first record for that key that is at least 7 days older and flag it 1. Then I take this record's date and again look for the first record for that key that is at least 7 days older and flag it 1. And so on. (All the other records are to be flagged 0.) Yes?

Comment: What is the expected result? The table with all 500 million records updated with the correct flag? Or a mere query result showing 500 million records each with the calculated flag? A query result showing all rows that are flagged 1?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - exactly the case of your first comment. Result - source table updated with the correct flag.

Comment: So you'll want to read the whole table, scan it sequentially and update each single record. I would write a PL/SQL function for this in which I'd loop through all records. If you expect most records to have to be flagged 0, then you may want to make a complete update to flag 0 first and then only update single records with 1 in the loop.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Tried to think about only SQL query, but seems you are right - PL/SQL function will be necessary... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to convert the table into partition but keep only the records which have a date difference of greater than 7 with previous record, if possible I suggest you delete the unwanted records if possible.

You will need to compare the adjacent rows, thus you can use `lag()` or `lead()` function.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

I think the below query might help:

```
SELECT pk, A1, A2, A3, A4, a_date
  FROM (SELECT PK, A1, A2, A3, A4, a_date,
       LAG (a_date, 1, 0)   OVER (ORDER BY A1, A2, A3, A4, a_date DESC) AS date_prev,
       a_date - LAG (a_date, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY A1, A2, A3, A4, a_date DESC) AS date_diff
          FROM tbl1)
 WHERE date_diff < 7
```

These are the records which you can delete.

Then you can create a partitioned table - list based partitioning- based on the structure of your table and then do insert into select.

Comment: Would it kill YOu to press the Y and O keys as well? If you want to be taken seriously by a professional community, it would help to nt ryt  lyk a Tngr on n old nkia dumfone?

Comment: Where did this idea come from?  There is nothing in the OP's question to suggest that they want to delete records.

Comment: @APC - thank you for answer. It seems to be good way with one exception: date_diff is designated between current and previous record. But it should be designated between current and last positive flagged.

e.g. you flagged first record. Second is compared with first. Lets assume the date_dif is less than 7, so the second record is negative flagged. 
Third record compares with first, not with second (first is possitive flagged). And so on...

Comment: @Darek: It is AmeyaN99  who wrote this answer, not APC. And you are saying that this solution doesn't do what you want, but you accepted it? Why?

Comment: My mistake, of course @AmeyaN99 - thank you for answer